# How to fix freetype incorrectly loading characters

Tags: c, opengl-es, textures, raspberry-pi3, freetype2

The FreeType library opens and loads a font without throwing errors, but when I try and use the character textures they're repeated and upsidedown.

I'm creating a graphics-based program using OpenGL, to deal with fonts and text I'm using FreeType. When I load the texture and set it up, the correct sizes and glyph attributes (width, advance etc...) are provided, but when I use the bitmap to create a texture and use that texture it's incorrect (as described earlier).

here is the initialisation code:

```c
FT_Init_FreeType(&ft);
FT_New_Face(ft, "Roboto.ttf", 0, &face);
FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 100);
getChars();
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
FT_Done_Face(face);
FT_Done_FreeType(ft);
```

here is the code that then gets the character textures:

```c
void getChars(){
  int index = 0;
  for (GLubyte c = 0; c < 128; c++){
    if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER)){
      printf("couldn't load character\n");
      continue;
    }
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1,&texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA,face->glyph->bitmap.width,face->glyph->bitmap.rows,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,face->glyph->bitmap.buffer);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    //glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    Character character = {texture, {face->glyph->bitmap.width, face->glyph->bitmap.rows}, {face->glyph->bitmap_left, face->glyph->bitmap_top}, face->glyph->advance.x};
    chars[index++] = character;
  }
  printf("Got characters\n");
}
```

I've commented out the glTexParameteri s that didn't make any difference to the way the texture was displayed

Here are the structures used to store the textures:

```c
typedef struct vec2 {
  float x;
  float y;
} vec2;

typedef struct Character {
  GLuint Texture;
  vec2 Size;
  vec2 Bearing;
  GLuint Advance;
} Character;

Character chars[128];
```

Finally here is the code that displays a string passed to it:

```c
void drawText(char* inString, float x, float y, float scale, colour col) {
  for (char* string = inString; *string != '\0'; string++){
    Character ch = chars[(int) *string];
    glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, ch.Texture);

    printf("character\n");

    float xpos = x + ch.Bearing.x * scale * 2 /glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    float ypos = y - (ch.Size.y - ch.Bearing.y) * scale * 2 /glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    float w = ch.Size.x * scale * 2 /glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    float h = ch.Size.y * scale * 2 /glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT);

    //draws the textured QUAD
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //set the colour of the quad the texutre blends with to white with the appropriate opacity
    glColor4f(col.R, col.G, col.B, col.A);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos);
    glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
    glVertex2f(xpos, ypos+h);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
    glVertex2f(xpos+w, ypos+h);
    glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);
    glVertex2f(xpos+w, ypos);
    glEnd();

    x += (ch.Advance >> 6) * scale * 2 /glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    printf("w %1.0f\n",w);
    printf("h %1.0f\n",h);
    printf("x %1.0f\n",xpos);
    printf("y %1.0f\n",ypos);
  }
}
```

I expect the normal text to be loaded, but as described earlier, each character looks like its own texture map

[this is the way the text looks (ignore the image behind it)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXhhD.png)

Comment: Are you sure that the format of the buffer (`face->glyph->bitmap.buffer`) is `GL_RGBA` rather than `GL_RED`?

Comment: I started with it as GL_RED, but nothing would display, so I changed it to GL_RGBA and got the result you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The buffer which is returned by [`FT_Load_Char`](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_load_char) contains one byte for each pixel of the glyph.
If you would use modern OpenGL the you could use the format `GL_RED` for the bitmap format and the internal texture image format. the rest would do the [Shader program](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader).
Since you use [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) you've to use a format that converts the byte value to an RGB value. Use `GL_LUMINANCE` for that. [`GL_LUMINANCE`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) converts *"into an RGBA element by replicating the luminance value three times for red, green, and blue and attaching 1 for alpha"*.

```c
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_LUMINANCE,
    face->glyph->bitmap.width,
    face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
    0,
    GL_LUMINANCE,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
);
```

Note that two-dimensional texturing has to be enabled, see [`glEnable`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glEnable.xml):

```cpp
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

---

If you want to draw the text with an transparent background, then you can use [`GL_ALPHA`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml):

```c
glTexImage2D(
    GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_ALPHA,
    face->glyph->bitmap.width,
    face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
    0,
    GL_ALPHA,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
);
```

When you draw the text, then you've to enable [`Blending`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending):

```c
void drawText(char* inString, float x, float y, float scale, colour col) {

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    // [...]

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
}
```

---

Further `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` should be called before `getChars();`.

Comment: I reckon OP will also have to use `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` before calling `glTexImage2D` to handle the case where `face->glyph->bitmap.width` doesn't divide by 4. (Or use `FT_Bitmap_Convert`)

Comment: This was kinda right, the only thing i needed to change was GL_RGBA to GL_ALPHA,